# Strange span align next to image

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Here's my stripped-down code:

```
<style>
div{
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
}
span{
    font-size:60pt;
    background-color:yellow;
}
img{
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
</style>

<div>
    <span>ASDF</span>
    <img src="foo"/>
</div>
```

(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pM2jE/)

How come the "ASDF" is misaligned with the rest of the DIV??

I suspect, somehow, that the bottom of the *word* "ASDF" is aligning with the rest of the DIV, and so the SPAN as a whole doesn't actually match up. I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the vertical-align for a span is "baseline", which will align the contained text to the bottom of the parent container.  Adding a:

`vertical-align: top;`

CSS property will align the top of the text to the top of the containing div.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; annoyed at CSS right now ._.

Answer (score 6):

Add this css to your image class

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 1):

use float:left or float: right in your  this might help you align your span and div